# h3 headings jump to full container width when they break to 2 lines

Tags: html, css

Thanks for the feedback, and sorry for the hasty post yesterday.

I have some `divs`, each containing an `h3` a div, and an image that needs to be behind them. I'm using `position:absolute` on the h3 and div instead of `background-image`
 because the cms correctly sets the image size, and I want the wrapper to match it automatically.

```
<div class="give-box">
  <h3>heading</h3>
  <div class="give-now-button"><a href="donate">give now</a></div>
  <img src="donate-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
.give-box h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: .2em;
  left: .2em;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #808080;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: .8em;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #e09e19;
}
.give-now-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}
```

Short headings look fine, but headings that break to 2 lines automatically fill the width of the container, so I get:

```
heading
-------

long
heading
-------------
```

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT7C8/1/)

Any ideas how I can shrink this down to the width of the text? I've tried every combination I can think of `margin`, `display:inline`, `display:inline-block`, `float`, etc.

Also, I can't break this heading up, e.g.

```
<h3>Longer</h3>
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

because it is dynamically generated by my cms.

Thanks

Comment: care to make a jsfiddle.net? Why are you using absolute positioning on the h3s?

Comment: ty making the `<div>`s `position:relative`

Comment: The line should shrink down. Since it's not, something odd is happening. Without and CSS, we are all just guessing. Could you either create a Fiddle or post your CSS? Preferably the second, because it's more future-proof.

Comment: I added the css and a jsfiddle, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline` without the absolute positioning will do the trick: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/jxopH

However, having a heading as `display: inline` isn't so convenient, so perhaps wrap it in a div ... although this is where design decisions can become more trouble than they are worth.